How to dockerize vite from a laravel inertia project?
I have a Laravel inertial application with vuejs and this application is dockerized in a container with Apache that has everything necessary. In addition, I have a mysql image running also in another container to connect the app with the database. I also have to run an npm install on my machine and then an npm run dev to run the front with vite. I would like to not have to install node and npm on my machine if not also containerize that part. I tried several times but no success.
This is my folder structure
LaravelVueInertial/
├── conf
├── docker-compose.yaml
├── dump
├── php
│   └── Dockerfile
└── src
    ├── app
    ├── artisan
    ├── bootstrap
    ├── composer.json
    ├── composer.lock
    ├── config
    ├── database
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── jsconfig.json
    ├── package.json
    ├── phpunit.xml
    ├── postcss.config.js
    ├── public
    ├── README.md
    ├── resources
    ├── routes
    ├── storage
    ├── tailwind.config.js
    ├── tests
    ├── vendor
    └── vite.config.js

This is my docker compose where I define three services, one for laravel, one for db and another which is the one I am trying to create for vite
services:
    php:
        build:
            context: ./php
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: crm
        volumes:
            - ./src:/var/www/html/
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        links:
            - mysql
            - vite
        networks:
            - default
    mysql:
        image: mysql
        container_name: mysql
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: secret
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
        volumes:
            - persistent:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
            - default
    vite:
        build:
            context: ./src
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: vite
        volumes:
            - ./src:/app
        ports:
            - "5173:5173"
        networks:
            - default

networks:
    default:

volumes:
  persistent:

The php and mysql image are built successfully but the vite image that I try to build ends immediately showing me the following
vite   | 
vite   | > dev
vite   | > vite
vite   | 
vite   | sh: 1: vite: not found
vite exited with code 127

The content of the dockerfile that is inside src is the following
# Use the official Node.js image as base
FROM node:latest

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json (if available) from src directory
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the application code from src directory
COPY . .

# Expose the port that the application will run on
EXPOSE 5173

# Command to run the application
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]

I don't have that much experience in docker but it was what occurred to me but I've been doing the same thing for a while without any different results.

You set your context path to ./php but that context only has the Dockerfile in it. This will prevent you from copying any other file to the docker image (see Docker contexts). Set the context path to . and dockerfile to ./php/Dockerfile and then in the Dockefile use COPY ./src/package*.json .

I home my docker-compose.yml will help you
version: '3'

networks:
    default:
        driver: bridge

volumes:
    database:
        driver: local

services:
    composer:
        image: composer
        command: install
        user: 1000:1000
        volumes:
            - ./:/app
    mail_server:
        image: "mailhog/mailhog:v1.0.0"
        ports:
            - "1026:1025" # smtp server
            - "8026:8025" # web UI http://localhost:8026
    web:
        image: nginx:1.17
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
            - .docker/web/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
        depends_on:
            - app
        networks:
            - default
    app:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: .docker/app/Dockerfile
        working_dir: /var/www
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        depends_on:
            - db
            - composer
    db:
        image: "mysql:8.0"
        restart: no
        ports:
            - 36062:3606
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
        volumes:
            - database:/var/lib/mysql
        env_file:
            - ./.env
    node:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: .docker/node/Dockerfile
        working_dir: /usr/src/app
        command: npm run watch
        user: 1000:1000
        volumes:
            - ./:/usr/src/app
            - /usr/src/app/node_modules

node Dockerfile
# Specify a base image
FROM node:alpine

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/node_modiles
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# Install app dependencies
COPY ./package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install
RUN chmod -R 777 /usr/src/app/node_modules/

don't forget to add the script to package.json
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "watch": "vite build --watch --emptyOutDir"
},

